# Which of the two laundry drain ports should I use for my washing machine?

Tags: washing-machine

I’m trying to connect my washing machine and can’t figure out which of these two outlets my drain pipe goes? I’ve always seen only one drain pipe outlet, but this one has two. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Can you probe in both of those openings with your finger to detect which one has a pipe connected to it? Seems unlikely that both have a pipe.

Comment: That's a non-standard installation, so the only way to know is to test things out.

Comment: What are the two pipes entering the box from the top connected to?

Comment: Do you have an air conditioner in the attic?  I suspect the pipes @Jerry_Contrary is asking about are condensate drains from attic air conditioning, if not you really should understand where they come from.

Comment: use a mirror to look down the holes .....  or take a picture of the inside of the holes .... it looks like they both go to the same space below